# Simple loop macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have the following problem:

[image]

Let me try to explain it. Basically I just want to re-arrange my data.
I want to plug in values in Column G, H, I and J.

hereafter I want to allocate each row in table G:I to the factor in J. I hope it makes sense, when you see the picture.

I created this code:

```
Sub order()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LR_G
    Dim LR_H
    Dim LR_I
    Dim LR_J

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    'Delete Range(A2:D)
    Range("A2:D" & sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Clear

    'Arange Order
    LR_G = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    LR_H = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    LR_I = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    LR_J = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

    Set DatarangeG = Range("G1:G" & LR_G)

      For J = 0 To LR_J - 2

        For i = 2 To LR_G

        Cells(i + J * (LR_G - 1), 1).Value = Cells(i, 7).Value
        Cells(i + J * (LR_G - 1), 3).Value = Cells(i, 8).Value
        Cells(i + J * (LR_G - 1), 4).Value = Cells(i, 9).Value
        Cells(i + J * (LR_G - 1), 2).Value = Cells(J + 2, 10).Value

        Next i

     Next J


End Sub
```

The code is a little slow, when I reach 20-30 rows in column G, H, I and J, but it is working for the first section.

My problem is, that the code, when it reach ID4 in Column G will allocate this to factor 1 and work is way throughout all the factors. I want it to ignore earlier factosr, when we have a space. So here I want ID4 to start with factor 4.

I have no idea on how to implement this. Any idea?

Comment: It is pretty unclear what the rules are which data is picked for G, H, I and J. So you need to be more specific and explain how data picking should work.

Comment: _I want it to ignore earlier factosr, when we have a space._   An idea could be to use an `if` statement with an exit clause such as `exit for` or a `Goto` statement to skip certain areas if a condition is met. To speed up the code look into `arrays` , the fastest way to do anything in Excel is to touch the sheet as little as possible.

Comment: I don't understand your algorithm at all. But, if it is working, to speed it up: `1` read the data table into a VBA array; `1` Apply your rules and collect the results into a Dictionary. `3` Write the Dictionary into a VBA array. `4` Write the VBA array back to the worksheet.  This usually results in an operation that executes in 1/5th - 1/10th the time of doing multiple read/writes to/from the worksheet.